# Show that there exists a monomorphism from $D_n$ to $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Problem: Show that there exists a monomorphism from $D_n$ to $S_n$, $n\geq 3$.

Write $D_n=\langle x,y\mid x^n=1, y^2=1, yx=x^{-1}y\rangle$.

Define a map $\phi:D_n\to S_n$ such that $ \phi(x)=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&...&n\\2&3&..&n\end{pmatrix}$ and

$\phi(y)=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&...&n-1&n\\1&n&n-1&...&3&2\end{pmatrix}$.

I want to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Let $a\in D_n$. Then $a=x^jy^k$ for some $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
So we need :$\phi(x^jy^k)=\phi(x^j)\phi(y^k)$ (**I don't know how to do that?**).

There is only such homomorphism:

Suppose there is other homomorohism say $\psi:D_n\to S_n$ such that $\psi(x)=\phi(x)$ and $\psi(y)=\phi(y)$.

Let $a\in D_n$. Then $a=x^jy^k$ for some $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then $\phi(x^jy^k)=\phi(x^j)\phi(y^k)=(\phi(x))^j(\phi(y))^k=(\psi(x))^j(\psi(y))^k=\psi(x^j)\psi(y^k)=\psi(x^jy^k)$.

Thus $\phi=\psi$. We're done(**Is it correct?**).

Comment: Do you know a set with $n$ elements on which $D_n$ operates?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: To prove that this $\phi$ is a homomorphism it is enough to show that it preserves the relations $x^n=1, y^2=1, yx=x^{-1}y$. It is slightly harder to prove that $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: @markvs Ahh. I think I can do this. Can you verify the next part?

Comment: @JohnInfinity How is $D_n$ defined geometrically?

Comment: The other part is trivial: if two homomorphisms coincide for generators, then they are equal.

Comment: To follow up on that hint, your presentation of $D_n$ dictates that we choose permutations for the monomorphic images of $x,y$ in $S_n$.

Comment: @markvs So what I have done is correct

Comment: Correct but the proof should work for arbitrary groups.

Comment: $D_n$ is the set of n symmetries, $x^i$ represents the rotation $i$ times so after $n$ rotation we find the same polygon with the same place as we started and $y$ represents the reflection so $y^2=1$.

Comment: @markvs Sorry, I didn't understand. What do you mean by arbitrary grouo here?

Comment: The claim is not true for $n=2$, by the way-- $S_2$ has too few elements.

Comment: @Troposphere Good catch, I edited. Thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is an **arbitrary** group generated by a set $X$ and $\phi,\psi$ are homomorphisms $G\to H$ that coincide on $X$ then $\phi=\psi$.

Comment: @markvs What's wrong with my proof? Kindly help me

Comment: Almost nothing is wrong. But you use the fact that every element of $D_n$ is a product of power of $x$ by a power of $y$ which requires a justification.

Comment: @markvs Alright thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you need the uniqueness? You have to prove that $\phi$ is injective, not unique.

Comment: Consider the subgroup $H=\{1,y\}\le D_n$ and the action of $D_n$ by left multiplication on the left quotient set $D_n/H$. The kernel of this acton is $\cap_{g\in D_n}g^{-1}Hg$, which is trivial for $n\ge 3$ because $H\cap x^{-1}Hx=\{1,y\}\cap \{1,xyx^{-1}\}=\{1,y\}\cap \{1,yx^2\}=\{1\}$. And $D_n/H$ has precisely $n$ elements.

Comment: @CAB Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Just watch out that $x$ and $x^{-1}$ have to be swapped in the RHS of the first equality above. I realized that too late to correct.

Comment: @CAB It's alright:)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131839/discussion-on-question-by-john-infinity-show-that-there-exists-a-monomorphism-fr).

Answer (score 1):

Call $H:=\{1,y\}\le D_n$. Now consider the action of $D_n$ by left multiplication of the left quotient set $D_n/H$. This action has kernel $\bigcap_{g\in D_n}g^{-1}Hg$, which is trivial for $n>2$ because then $H\cap x^{-1}Hx$ is trivial: in fact, $x^{-1}Hx=\{1,x^{-1}yx\}=\{1,yx^2\}$, and $y\ne yx^2$ as soon as $n>2$ (because then $x^2\ne 1$). But the size of $D_n/H$ is precisely $n$, and hence $D_n$ acts faithfully on a set of $n$ elements or, equivalently, it embeds into $S_n$.